# What are TCP Port 5445 and UDP Port 3935 used for on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: tcp, windows-server-2016, udp

I'm facing a dilemma, I built 2 physical servers and for some reason for all the IP addresses assigned to that server it's listening on Port 5445 (TCP) and also 3935 (UDP).

Applying the same configuration but in VMWARE, it doesn't listen on these ports.

I'm trying to figure out why? It lists process ID 4 and the owner is "System" NT Kernal and System.

At first, I thought it was SMB2.0 and I disabled that via Registry, but it didn't make a difference.

Any guidance on where and how to look will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

5445 TCP is SMB Over DMA:
https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?=&skey=6&page=135

3935 UDP is used by [SDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Description_Protocol) Port Mapper Protocol:
https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?&page=75

Comment: I have seen those port mappings, I'm looking on guidance on how to turn it off, so it doesn't listen on those ports.

Comment: @Henry, that is not at all what your question asks. It asks how to find what those are, and this answer answered that. Perhaps you should ask a new question about how to turn those services off.

Comment: @Ron, I don't have those enabled, so that's not what it is. I Just don't know what's causing it.  A standard port list of possible items that use it. Doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Henry, my point is that your question is not asking what your comment is asking. You could edit your question, which is bad form when you have an answer to the original question, or you could ask a new question. You just do not modify your original question by a comment to an answer that answered the original question. SE site are, explicitly, not discussion forums. You ask a question and get an answer to the question.

Comment: @RonMaupin I think you're just not understanding what's being asked. If the solution was "search google for port #" don't you think I would have done that like 20000 times.

Comment: @Henry, where in your original question does it ask about "_guidance on how to turn it off, so it doesn't listen on those ports,_" as your comment says? You original question is about "_guidance on where and how to look_," and that is what the answer provides. Can you see how those are two completely different things?

Comment: @Ron The question is "I'm trying to figure out why?"  Why does the same build in VMWARE doesn't have this issue vs a Physical server build. I need guidance on where to look. Just because someone says hey look these ports are used by XYZ. That doesn't solve the question on the difference in VMware vs Physical build and the behavior that's exhibited.

Comment: The title clearly states “what are TCP/5445 and UDP/3935 used for!” This question is answered by Seisstone. Yes you could’ve googled that yourseld but your question (bosy) did not indicate you bothered to do so as it does not say what these ports are used for. The body also does not explicitly ask how to turn those off. Agreed, there should also be an answer on why it opens the ports on a physical machine and not in VMware.